# Problem with apt after moving abroad

Tags: apt, software-sources

I recently moved to the UK from Poland. Now I'm getting this error whenever I try to install any package with `apt-get install`:

```
Following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.2.0-36-generic: Requires: linux-image-4.2.0-36-generic but will not be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.2.0-42-generic: Requires: linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic but will not be installed
 linux-image-generic: Requires: linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic but will not be installed
```

I can tell that it's a problem with dependencies. But is it an issue with the kernel or sources.list?

Comment: Can you install packages, or is this just a side error?

Comment: I cannot install packages with apt-get install, I can only install it with dpkg from already downloaded file

Comment: I believe it is there because of change in your repositories i.e., source list.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update` and then try your original command again.